# I'm working on an enrolment register. I'm struggling with the following method RemoveMember()

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public void EnrollMember() {
    Request.instance().setMemberName(getName("Enter member name"));
    Request.instance().setMemberAddress(getName("Enter address"));
    Request.instance().setMemberPhone(getName("Enter phone"));
    Request.instance().setFeePaid(getName("Enter the fee paid"));
    Result result = store.addMember(Request.instance());
    if (result.getResultCode() != Result.OPERATION_COMPLETED) {
        System.out.println("Could not add member");
    } else {
        System.out.println(result.getMemberName() + "'s id is " + result.getMemberId());
    }
 }
public void addProduct() {
  Request.instance().setProductId(getName("Enter Product ID"));
  Request.instance().setProductName(getName("Enter product Name"));
  Request.instance().setProductPrice(getName("Enter product price"));
  Request.instance().setProductReorder(getName("Enter the product reorder amount"));
  Result result= store.addProduct(Request.instance());
  if (result.getResultCode() != Result.OPERATION_COMPLETED) {
      System.out.println("Could not add product");
  } else {
      System.out.println(result.getProductName() + "'s id is " + result.getProductId());
  }
}
public void RemoveMember(){

   //If a valid id is received, the corresponding member is removed. The system would need the member's ID for this purpose.
   //Only one member is removed when this functionality is invoked
   //Data is in a LinkedList

   System.out.println("Enter a valid ID");
   Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
   String validId = input.nextLine();
   Result result= store.addMember(Request.instance());
   
   if(result.getMemberId().equals(validId)){
       System.out.println("Member removed");
       
   }else{
       
   }
   
   
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the data are inside LinkedList, you must iterate either way (even if you call  `result.get(index);` or ask `result.contains(member);` (just remmeber thatthe Member class needs to have correctly overridden the equals() method, otherwise it would not find the member).

Therefore I would use an `List#Iterator` and when the object is found, you can call `iterator.remove();` to remove the object from the list. If it would be possible, I would suggest to use different means of storing the data you want to find/access later using a identifier, for examle a `HashMap<String, Member>`. Otherwise you are risking performance issues when the list grows larger.

I have tried to adjust your RemoveMember method bellow. Hope this answers you question.

```
public void RemoveMember() {

    //If a valid id is received, the corresponding member is removed. The system would need the member's ID for this purpose.
    //Only one member is removed when this functionality is invoked
    //Data is in a LinkedList

    System.out.println("Enter a valid ID");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String validId = input.nextLine();
    Result result = store.addMember(Request.instance());

    // I am assuming a class "Member" and "LinkedList<Member> result" for readability 
    for (Iterator<Member> iterator = store.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Member m = iterator.next();
        if (m.getMemberId().equals(validId)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @petersagini Well, that might certainly be so, since you share only part of the code. Then either you need to post something that compiles (which I don't think is the way it works here), or you must adjust the example and make it work. Also you can say what the errors are?